# Is there any way to make circular progress bar beyond 100%?

Tags: swift, animation, progress-bar, loading

At first I've think to use pie chart but then it clicked me to use circular progress instead and now it need to go beyond 100%.

Is there any way to modify any existing circular progress bar SDK for swift or any alternate way to achieve this behaviour?

How about using Donut Graph or something?

Edit: It is gif, that is attached. Don't know why it's not playing as gif should! (you can check out by clicking on it)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up using [KDCircularProgress](https://github.com/kaandedeoglu/KDCircularProgress) for this.

```
import KDCircularProgress // I'm using (1.5.4)

@IBOutlet weak var progress: UIView!

private var progressBar: KDCircularProgress?
private var totalPer = 120.0

private func setupProgressUI() {
        let progress = KDCircularProgress(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        self.progress.addSubview(progress)
        progress.startAngle = -90
        progress.progressThickness = 0.8
        progress.trackThickness = 0.8
        progress.trackColor = .darkGray
        progress.roundedCorners = true
        progress.set(colors: UIColor.orange)
        progress.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        progress.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.progress.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        progress.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.progress.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        progress.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.progress.topAnchor).isActive = true
        progress.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.progress.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.progressBar = progress
}

private func setupProgressData() {
    self.progressBar?.trackColor = .darkGray
    self.setProgress(percentage: self.totalPer)
}

private func setProgress(percentage: Double) {
    var percentage = percentage
    if percentage > 100 {
        percentage -= 100
        self.progressBar?.animate(fromAngle: 0, toAngle: 360, duration: 2) { isComplete in
            if isComplete && percentage > 0 {
                self.progressBar?.trackColor = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
                self.setProgress(percentage: percentage)
            }
        }
    } else {
        self.progressBar?.animate(fromAngle: 0, toAngle: percentage * 3.6, duration: 2, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]